Glide is showing the placeholder in CircularImageView until i refresh it shows the image from the url
I have a pretty basic load image from server line code:
glideRequests.loadUrl(iv_hangout_logo!!, finalDatum.hangout_logo, R.drawable.ic_default_image, isLoadThumb = false)
glide is stuck on placeholder until i refresh the page it shows the photo from the url
i have tried this but isn't working i don't know why is that
Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).dontAnimate().into(view)
